# "run a sh file from jsp page code error"

Tags: java, html, linux, shell, jsp

I have a sh file in my `D:\TrinitiApps28\tabimpl\keystore\my_script.sh`, whose code is which is running in putty giving the output as *"hello world"*,
I have a `shellandantscriptrunner.jsp`, in which I have to call this `my_script.sh` file to get output as `"hello world"`.
What code should I add and I am getting error like `create process error=193,          create process error=2, and read all, tried all but failed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a script using java in your jsp page:

```
try {
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\TrinitiApps28\\tabimpl\\keystore\\sh my_script.sh");
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println("exit code: " + p.exitValue());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

After a bit of researching, agree with [Gyro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2136795/gyro-gearless) and from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/120049/426633)

> You're on Windows `CMD.EXE`. It uses a different syntax to execute commands. You'll need to use `sh name.sh`, assuming that you've got `Cygwin` or similar installed.
>
> **To clarify, Windows does not have a built-in utility to support .sh files. To run such, you'll need to install a third-party tool such as [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).**

Comment: I doubt plain windows will recognize a shell script. And there is something wrong with the backslashes...

Comment: we use "out.println()" or "System.out.println()" syntax while writing code in jsp??

Comment: InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        osr.write("");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line= null;
        out.println(provideshellscript);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
             System.out.println(line);
            }

Comment: this syntaxes also i am using, will i delete it.. but same Create Process error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application D:/TrinitiApps28/tabimpl/keystore/my_script.sh is coming when giving the path,

Comment: where i can see "my update and new links" button? i am using putty and no cmd.exe.

Comment: what `buton`? *my update and new links* are **in my updated answer**? You even know what is `putty`?